# How to make download link for crawler output in Flask?

Tags: python, linux, nginx, flask, supervisord

I have a Flask web application when user click on button a crawler starts to work and creates a csv output, i want to create a download link for download the file that creates today. this is my code:

```
import datetime
today= datetime.date.today()
@users.route('/download')
@login_required
def download():
   path = f'../CrawlBot/Output/All/allsites-{today}.csv'
   try:
       return send_file(path, as_attachment=True)
   except:
       flash('File not found for today! run Crawler.', 'danger')
       return redirect(url_for('main.home'))
```

but this is downloads the last time i reloaded supservisorctl and if i want to download today's file i should login to server and reload supervisor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I think the issues is your variable's scope. The variable "today" is loaded when the program starts. If you want the variable "today" to actually be the day today each time the function is run, you'll want to update the variable when the function runs.

To do that, simply move

```
today= datetime.date.today()
```

inside of the download function. That way it'll be recalculated whenever the download function is called.